# Array to string conversion in php check my code

Tags: php, html

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="mysql.php" method="post">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"></br>
    last Name:  <input type="text" name="lname">< </br>
    What is your favrite subject <input type="text" name="subject"></input> </br>
    Your Age : <input type="text" name="age"></input> </br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" ></input>
    <input type="reset" name="rs"></input>
    </form>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST\['submit'\]) ){
    $_sa = mysql_connect( "localhost","Ali","pakistan");
    if (!$_sa){ 
        die("can not caonnect".msql_error());
    }

    /*  ----------- condition ----------------------
    if (empty($_POST\[fname\])) {
        echo "First name required";
    }
    ------------------condition end ----------------- */

    mysql_select_db("google", $_sa );

    line 46--  $sql = "INSERT INTO info (firstname,lastname,subject,age) VALUES ('$_POST \[fname\]','$_POST \[lname\]','$_POST \[subject\]', '$_POST \[age\]'')";

    mysql_query($sql,$_sa);
    mysql_close($_sa);

    }

     ?>][1]
```

// when I run my code its give me error of

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql.php on
>   line 46

Comment: get rid of the \ in `$_POST\['submit'\]` and same for the other ones and extra quote in `[age\]''`. You can also safefy get rid of `</input>` they're not valid closing tags.

Comment: In other words, your code is stitched with syntax errors. Whoever wants to fix this, please... *be my guest*. ;-)

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: *Time to get out the "YIPE!" sign there, right Sam?* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: *Gravity sucks Ralph!* @Fred-ii-

Comment: *I can hear the whistle blowin' all the way down Sam.......* @JayBlanchard ♫ ssSSSsssss..... ♫ **CRASH!!!** - *"On with the show this is it"*. ♫ - Ah biddy biddy biddy, that's all folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`$sql = "INSERT INTO info (firstname,lastname,subject,age) VALUES ('{$_POST ['fname']}','{$_POST ['lname']}','{$_POST ['subject']}', '{$_POST ['age']}')";`

Explanation:

$_POST is an `array`
So, you need to take care of it while accessing

And, If arrays are accessed inside String, then we should use `{}`
For example: `{$_POST['subject']}`

Comment: Why should the OP "do this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. There are so many syntax errors and other errors in the question that fixing the query will be of no use by itself.

Comment: `{}` is required, Try once

Comment: Whatever, output on `{}` removal:
`string(131) "INSERT INTO info (firstname,lastname,subject,age) VALUES ('Array ['fname']','Array ['lname']','Array ['subject']', 'Array ['age']')" `

Comment: This line was the code-stopper.
Let him take care of the rest

Comment: 10-4 @AkhilVL! Good call!

Comment: @AkhilVL now my record is adding ..  $sql = "INSERT INTO info (firstname,lastname,subject,age) VALUES ('{$_POST [fname]}','{$_POST [lname]}','{$_POST [subject]}', '{$_POST [age]}')";   by doing is

Comment: @AkhilVL  the only error is there is this one by its not make any problem but wye is this error is there -------------------Notice: Use of undefined constant fname - assumed 'fname' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql.php on line 47

Comment: @alishahid Write like this: `{$_POST ['fname']}`

Comment: @AkhilVL its gone ! lol but now its showing data like this in phpmyadmin Array [firstname] old data was there before this {$_POST ['fname']}  after this its like Array [firstname]
Array [lastname]
Array [subject]
NULL

Comment: @alishahid Can you write the code here. Only `INSERT INTO info` line

Comment: @AkhilVL <pre> <code> $sql = "INSERT INTO info (firstname,lastname,subject,age) VALUES ({$_POST ['fname']},{$_POST ['lname']},{$_POST ['subject']}, {$_POST ['age'] })";

Comment: @AkhilVL this one is showing Array [firstname]  in the data base

Comment: @alishahid Replace with this:
`$sql = "INSERT INTO info (firstname,lastname,subject,age) VALUES ('{$_POST['fname']}','{$_POST['lname']}','{$_POST['subject']}', '{$_POST['age'] }')";`

Comment: @AkhilVL thank you so much ! it works im new in this soo ! :) i will be in how can i contact you if i need help ?

Comment: @alishahid That would be chargeable! :)

Comment: amazing that other error are not causing him problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra single quote written at the end.

Comment: At the end of what? There are so many errors in that question, it's not funny. *You call this an answer?*

Comment: the single quote is after '$_POST \[age\]' on line 46.Please delete it and check

Comment: There are so many errors that fixing one single quote will not repait the code for the OP.

Comment: Man i know but i had to tell one wrongs out of many and somebody downvoted me.Though i pointed out a mistake.I am not that skilled like some of you.

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant fname - assumed 'fname' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql.php on line 47

Notice: Use of undefined constant lname - assumed 'lname' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql.php on line 47

Notice: Use of undefined constant subject - assumed 'subject' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql.php on line 47

Notice: Use of undefined constant age - assumed 'age' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql.php on line 47